# SQlite Database NullPointerException when inserting data when button in dialog is clicked

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been working on creating and inserting data in table. Currently I have a dialog box with expandable list. User selects few things and clicks done; it calls up a class which creates the table and insert data.

---

The flow of program is :

**MainActivity** -> onCreate (added adapters, make dialog with expandable list) -> onResume -> callAsync -> doInBackground (DAO instance, instance.open, doStuff, instance.close).

**DAO constructor** -> (helper instance); DAO open -> (db = helper.getWritableDatabase())

**Helper** onCreate -> execSQL commands -> Tables (db) constructor -> all tables made s

**Dialog** -> makeStuff -> onClick -> (calculate array to be used to make table) -> Tables(array) constructor -> ERROR here showing NPE.

---

I have pushed the current files to [github](https://github.com/sahildave/SQLite%5fListView/tree/master/src/com/example/try%5fsqlite%5furl). Is it that after the onCreate method of helper is completed, the database is closed? I dont see any other reason that database is showing a null pointer exception. Everything was working well till last night before adding TABLE_NCUP.

Logcat

```
    04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560): Process: com.example.try_sqlite_url, PID: 2560
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at com.example.try_sqlite_url.Tables.<init>(Tables.java:22)
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at com.example.try_sqlite_url.DialogMaker$1.onClick(DialogMaker.java:70)
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-14 10:12:26.654: E/AndroidRuntime(2560):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @laalto, I reckon the variable I am making two different instances right now, and second instance does not have `database` initialized. So I tried using a `getInstance` way by refering to [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html). Now the `instance` while calling Tables through onClick in dialog is null. The changed code are:

Tables.java

```
public static Tables tableInstance;

public static Tables getInstance(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if (tableInstance == null) {
        Log.d("TABLE", "in Table getInstance db");
        tableInstance = new Tables(db);
    }
    return tableInstance;
}

public static Tables getInstance(int[] array) {
    Log.d("TABLE", "in Table getInstance array");
    return tableInstance;
}
```

Calling the tables instance after clicking button in dialog:

```
Tables instance = Tables.getInstance(ncup);
instance.Tables(ncup); // <----- THIS IS NULL!
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: is table creatted in the database?

Comment: Post you Logcat please. Especially the NPE.

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace with relevant code here.

Comment: Added. Sorry I forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Tables` has two constructors and the one you're using `public Tables(int[] ncup_array)` does not initialize the `database` member variable.

Comment: Yes, but when the `public Tables(SQLiteDatabase db)` constructor is called in the onCreate, doesnt it initialize the field variable `database`? Wouldn't the member variable `database` be same as field variable?

Comment: Didn't read the code that much, but only one constructor ever gets called per instance. If you constructed a `Tables` object that way before, it initialized that instance. The other `Tables` instance does not have its `database` initialized.

Comment: Once a `Tables` instance is called in onCreate of the helper class. That is the first constructor, that does initialize the `database` field variable. Second time, `Tables` instance is called when a button in a dialog box is clicked, that time the second constructor is called. 

Next thing I am wondering is how would I pass a database from a DialogMaker class to Tables class?

Comment: Yes and the other `Tables` object has its own `database` variable which is not initialized.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. Next thing I am wondering is how would I pass a database from a DialogMaker class to Tables class?